# SQL - Restoring deleted records with key field intact

Tags: sql-server

I deleted some customer records with customer number being the key. Is there a way to append them back in and keep the same customer number. I looked at changing the field "identity specification" but the process of switching it on and off looks risky and beyond my skill level.

Comment: It's not risky at all if you properly set it `ON`, insert your data, then back `OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`set identity_insert` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

```
set identity_insert dbo.customers on;
  insert into dbo.customers (CustomerNumber,CustomerName)
    values (8675309,'Jenny');
set identity_insert dbo.customers off;
```

Comment: If you are really feeling paranoid, put the above code inside a transaction. That should ensure that no other data will be added during this window.